# Compare h:ia time format string php - not working

Tags: php, datetime, datetime-format

Example, my tmp array is:

```
Array
(
    [checkin] => 11:00am
    [checkout] => 12:00pm
    [day_from] => 09:59am
    [day_to] => 06:00pm
)
```

I am using below code to compare time, but in both cases it always displays 'hello' even the checkin time and checkout time both are inside day-from and day-to range.

Actually, this functionality is to check that if the guest's checkin and checkout time is inside restaurants opening from-to hours or not?

Any help will be greatly appreciated! Thanks in advance :-)

```
$tmp_arr = array();
$tmp_arr['checkin'] = $checkin = date('h:ia',strtotime($checkin));
$tmp_arr['checkout'] = $checkout = date('h:ia',strtotime($checkout));
$tmp_arr['day_from'] = $day_from = date('h:ia',strtotime($day_from));
$tmp_arr['day_to'] = $day_to = date('h:ia',strtotime($day_to));
print_r($tmp_arr);
if($checkin>=$day_from && $checkin<=$day_to){
    echo "hi";
}
else{
    echo "hello";
}
if($checkout>=$day_from && $checkout<=$day_to){
    echo "hi";
}
else{
    echo "hello";
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should just convert the time strings into unix timestamps using strtotime. Then you can compare them the way you anticipated.

```
$checkin = '11:00am';
$checkout = '12:00pm';
$day_from = '09:59am';
$day_to = '06:00pm';

$tmp_arr = array();
$tmp_arr['checkin'] = $checkin = strtotime($checkin);
$tmp_arr['checkout'] = $checkout = strtotime($checkout);
$tmp_arr['day_from'] = $day_from = strtotime($day_from);
$tmp_arr['day_to'] = $day_to = strtotime($day_to);
print_r($tmp_arr);
if($checkin>=$day_from && $checkin<=$day_to){
    echo "hi";
}
else{
    echo "hello";
}
if($checkout>=$day_from && $checkout<=$day_to){
    echo "hi";
}
else{
    echo "hello";
}
```